# Sum of ints and floats in a multi nested list

Tags: python, recursion, sum

```
def recListSum(lst):
    '''Takes an arbitrarily nested list as a parameter and returns the sum of
the numbers in the list'''
    if len(lst)==0:
        return 0
    if len(lst) > 0:
        val = recListSum(lst[1:])+recListSum(lst[0])
        if type(lst[0]) != list:
            if type(lst[0])==float or type(lst[0])==int:
                return val
        if type(lst[0])==list and len(lst[0])>0:
            val = recListSum(lst[1:])+recListSum(lst[0])
            return val
```

Comment: What's your question? :)

Comment: I keep getting a object of type 'int' has no len() error @user3697163

Comment: Which line? You need to edit the question to include all these relevant details. People aren't going to pick through this with a comb to find the errors.

Comment: Post full traceback in your question. And most likely when you're passing the `lst` into the function you're not doing it correctly, hence the error. But can't tell me without traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you are giving the len() function an integer value. Since a number doesn't really have a length, that is going to throw an error.

I would check that "lst" is actually a list when you are assuming that it is (maybe some bug before calling this method resulted in "lst" becoming an integer).

I think the first condition of your last if statement is protecting the len() function there, but it never hurts to check it out if I'm wront about "lst" just being an integer sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```
def recListSum(lst):
    '''Takes an arbitrarily nested list as a parameter and returns the sum of
the numbers in the list'''
    # handle trivial cases
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]

    # sum and unfold
    total = 0
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            new_lst += item
        else:
            total += item
    new_lst.append(total)

    # recurse
    return recListSum(new_lst)
```

Comment: this yields aTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    recFloatCount([[12],4,6])
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 10, in recFloatCount
    val = recFloatCount(lst[1:])+lst[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is listed below.
I assume that `lst` are `list` which consist of `list`, `int` or `float`

```
def recListSum(lst):
    if type(lst) in (int,float):
        return lst
    elif not type(lst) is list:
        raise TypeError
    elif len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return recListSum(lst[0])+recListSum(lst[1:])
```